# Properly filtering DataGridView DataSource with buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, filter

The main goal is to not alter the DataSource. So, when I get my result set, I want to filter based on this result set ALWAYS. I have been using a DataGridView and the pre-existing code is limited to adding the rows directly to the DataGridView rather than using a DataTable.

I have tried this and it works but I feel as though it is not incredibly efficient and was wondering if there is an optimal solution that doesn't require looping through.

This is on a button press:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
    {
     if (this.dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = "Sleeping Disorder")
     {
       this.dataGridView.Rows[i].Visible = true;
     }
     else
     {
       this.dataGridView.Rows[i].Visible = false;
      }
    }
```

I researched a bit and saw people using DataTables but I am not permitted to re-work the entire code-set, so I am wondering if I can do this without a DataTable or if I have to use a DataTable, could I use a method to populate a Table with my DataGridView and go from there?

Data initially comes from a MySQL query.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the source of data for the population of the grid? I know you add the rows in manually, but where does the data come from initially?

Comment: Added an edit (comes through MySQL query)

Comment: why dont you use a loop to fill a datatable, and use the datatable as datasource for the datagrid. Than you can filter your datatable very easy

Comment: I'd still personally say use a datatable. It is not a re-work to do so. You're replacing one filtering routine with another. Populate the datatable which leaves your data source intact and then bind your grid to the datatable.

Comment: I see, so if I went the DataTable route I would do something like table.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("[Sleeping Disorder] = " + sleepButton.Text);

Comment: Something like that. I can't recall the exact syntax. You can also do Selects on the datatable as well. I have to go now.. so hope you get this sorted. Cheers

Comment: You definitly don't want your data stored directly in the DataGridView. You want to be running a datatable and a bindingsource to be able to use the BindingSource.Filter attribute. Your actual routine using DataGridViewRow.Visible Feature will cause loads of troubles with currency-manager exceptions. It might be some work to change the existing code, but sooner or later it will become absolutly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

a snippet I use to filter a DataGrid

```
// DevicesGrid is the DataGrid with the data I want to filter
// this next line gets the textbox contents to filter on, you won't need this
Controls.TextBox textbox = sender as Controls.TextBox;
        ICollectionView cvs = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DevicesGrid.ItemsSource);

   // doing the filter
// A PortResult is what is in the collection, replace that with whatever is in yours
        cvs.Filter = new Predicate<object>(item =>
        {
            PortResult pr = item as PortResult;
            if (pr.Name.Contains(textbox.Text))
            { return true; }
            else { return false; }
        });
```